# Constructors and objects

Tags: java

So I just learned about Constructors. I wrote this program myself, and I want to incorporate constructors into this program(AS it could use it!). Also I get null instead of a symbol type but other than that the program runs fine(Thinking maybe constructors can fix the null).

My main issue currently is that I don't want to take out the class called "Options"(or is it called a method class?). But yet I still want to use the constructor, to get rid of "choice" and "getOperatives".

While I'm aware my "Options" class(Should it be capitalized), can just simply go in main, as it's only going to be used once, I'm focusing on understanding the concepts not so much it being robust(but still being robust).

```
    //Call objects
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    css cssAccess = new css();
    //Call Variables
    int choice;
    int x,y;
    int total;
    String type;
    String str;

    //Give Choices & Input Choice

    choice = scan.nextInt();

    //Get 2 itmes to operate on

    System.out.println("Please enter two items to operate on");
    x = scan.nextInt();
    y = scan.nextInt();

    //Pass in operatives AND then choice
    cssAccess.getOperatives(x,y);
    cssAccess.arithmeticDecision(choice);
    //Grab total
    total = cssAccess.answer();
    //Grab type of operation user entered
    type = cssAccess.arithmeticSymbol();
    //Output Results
    System.out.println(x + type + y + " = " + total);
```

And Here is the file with all my classes in it

```
public class css {


    //Declare Variables
    private int getChoice;
    private int input1,input2;
    private int total;
    private String symbol;
    int refchoice;

     public void choice(int choice){

       getChoice = choice;
    }

    public void getOperatives(int x, int y){
        input1 = x;
        input2 = y;
    }
        public void Options(){
        System.out.println("Would you like to add(1)");
        System.out.println("Would you like to subtract(2)");
        System.out.println("Would you like to multiply(3)");
        System.out.println("Would you like to Divide(4)");
        System.out.println("Or would you like to find the remainder(5)");
    }

    public void arithmeticDecision(int choice){
        choice = refchoice;
        switch (refchoice){
            case 5:total = input1 % input2;
                break;
            case 4:total = input1 / input2;
                break;
            case 3:total = input1 * input2;
                break;
            case 2:total = input1 - input2;
                break;
            case 1:total = input1 + input2;
                break;

        }
    }

    public int answer(){

        return total;
    }

    public String arithmeticSymbol(){
        switch (Integer.toString(refchoice)){
            case "5":symbol = "%";
                break;
            case "4":symbol = "/";
                break;
            case "3":symbol = "*";
                break;
            case "2":symbol = "-";
                break;
            case "1":symbol = "+";
                break;


        }
        return symbol;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Also I'm thinking, I might want to invoke a toString method for the result of things.

Comment: First off, you're *already* using a constructor. Every class has a default, implicit constructor that takes no arguments, which is how you can instantiate a class via the new keyword. Second, what makes you think you "need" a constructor other than the default? Don't use something simply because it exists -- use it because you actually need it.

Comment: You need to think a bit more about what a constructor is -- it's there to help initialize your object. What is it about your class that needs initialization? It's important to understand the "why" of a concept rather than stopping at "what" and "how."

Comment: I think I need to initialize a constructor to get 3 sets of input(choice, and the two variables to operate on).

Comment: I would prefer to have a constructor because it would theoretically kill many birds with one stone in the future, and in this case 2. I'm going to watch more videos about constructors and make some modifications.